# SVG + Handlebars - Rotating a graphic and adjusting proportions

Tags: svg, handlebars.js

I'm trying to rotate a graphic within a svg but i'm having the hardest time.

Below image is what I'm trying to achieve, a rotated version by switching the original width with the height but keeping all original proportions
I've tried rotating the individual object and rotating the full on  but nothing comes even remotely close to the end result. the screenshot below comes from my front end webpage, the backend unfortunately needs an svg to print labels in the correct location.

let me know if anything else is needed to be able to troubleshoot this

Screenshot of how it would look coming out of your printer:
[image: Screenshot of how it would look coming out of your printer]

Desired End Result (badges to wear on your person):
[image: Desired End Result (badges to wear on your person)]

Handlebars template:

```
<svg id="svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="{{paper.width}}{{paper.unit}}" height="{{paper.height}}{{paper.unit}}" viewBox="0 0 {{paper.width}} {{paper.height}}">

  {{#each papers}}
    <g transform="translate({{leftOffset}}, {{topOffset}})">
      {{#each badges}}
        <!--Badge {{@index}}-->
        <g transform="translate({{leftOffset}}, {{topOffset}})">
            <svg width="{{width}}" height="{{height}}" viewBox="0 0 {{width}} {{height}}">
              {{#each objects}}
                {{#if placeholder}}
                  <!--Text: {{placeholder}}-->
                  <svg x="{{x}}"  y="{{y}}" width="{{width}}" height="{{height}}">
                      <text x="{{leftOffset}}" y="{{topOffset}}" text-anchor="{{alignment}}" font-size="{{fontSize}}" font-family="{{fontName}}" font-weight="{{fontWeight}}" font-style="{{fontStyle}}" fill="{{fontColor}}" transform="rotate({{rotation}} {{rotationX}} {{rotationY}})">
                          {{value}}
                      </text>
                  </svg>
                {{else}}
                  {{#if background}}
                  <!--Background: {{name}}-->
                  {{else}}
                    {{#if isDropdown}}
                      <!--Image: {{value}}-->
                    {{else}}
                      {{#if file}}
                        <!--Image: Uploaded - {{cid}}-->
                      {{else}}
                        <!--Image: {{name}}-->
                      {{/if}}
                    {{/if}}
                  {{/if}}
                  <svg preserveAspectRatio="{{aspectRatio}}" x="{{leftOffset}}" y="{{topOffset}}" width="{{width}}" height="{{height}}" viewBox="0 0 {{backWidth}} {{backHeight}}">
                    <image xlink:href="{{href}}" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" transform="rotate({{rotation}} {{rotationX}} {{rotationY}})"/>
                  </svg>
                {{/if}}
              {{/each}}
            </svg>
        </g>
      {{/each}}
    </g>
  {{/each}}

    <defs>
        <style type="text/css">
          {{#each googleFonts}}
            <link xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" href="{{url}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
          {{/each}}
          {{#each fonts}}
            {{fontFace}}
          {{/each}}
        </style>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Completed example:

```html
<svg id="svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="8.267in" height="11.692in" viewBox="0 0 8.267 11.692">
    
        <g transform="translate(0.27906, 1.62367)">
            <!--Badge 0-->
            <g transform="translate(0, 0)">
                <svg width="3.8548" height="2.1114" viewBox="0 0 3.8548 2.1114">
                            <!--Image: belgian-flag(2).jpg-->
                      <svg preserveAspectRatio="none" x="1.2888000000000002" y="0.172" width="0.4915" height="0.4988" viewBox="0 0 226 400">
                        <image xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/QLTDr7J.jpg;" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" transform="rotate(90 200 113)"/>
                      </svg>
<!--Image: Albania.png-->
<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" x="2.3009999999999997" y="0.2335" width="0.5038" height="0.5036" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
                        <image xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/gFbTCmq.png;" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" transform="rotate(90 24 24)"/>
                      </svg>
<!--Text: Name-->
<svg x="1.5157" y="0.2712" width="2.0202" height="0.48227999999999993">
                          <text x="2.1817" y="0.3122" text-anchor="end" font-size="0.2225" font-family="Arial" font-weight="400" font-style="normal" fill="#000000" transform="rotate(90 1.0101 0.24113999999999997)">
                              DFGHDFGH
                          </text>
                      </svg>
<!--Text: Title-->
<svg x="1.5526" y="1.2349" width="2.0202" height="0.47652">
                          <text x="1.2227999999999999" y="0.2818833333333333" text-anchor="end" font-size="0.16666666666666666" font-family="Arial" font-weight="400" font-style="italic" fill="#000000" transform="rotate(90 1.0101 0.23826)">
                              dfghdgh
                          </text>
                      </svg>
</svg>
</g>
<!--Badge 1-->
<g transform="translate(3.8548, 0)">
  <svg width="3.8548" height="2.1114" viewBox="0 0 3.8548 2.1114">
                            <!--Image: belgian-flag(2).jpg-->
                      <svg preserveAspectRatio="none" x="0.4193" y="1.3148" width="0.4924" height="0.5027" viewBox="0 0 400 226">
                        <image xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/QLTDr7J.jpg;" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" transform="rotate(0 113 200)"/>
                      </svg>
  <!--Image: Albania.png-->
  <svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" x="0.4808" y="0.3016" width="0.5078" height="0.5027" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
                        <image xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/gFbTCmq.png;" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" transform="rotate(0 24 24)"/>
                      </svg>
  <!--Text: Name-->
  <svg x="1.5119" y="0.2707" width="2.02212" height="0.48263999999999996">
                          <text x="1.6851" y="0.3261" text-anchor="end" font-size="0.25" font-family="Arial" font-weight="400" font-style="normal" fill="#000000" transform="rotate(0 1.01106 0.24131999999999998)">
                              DFGHDF
                          </text>
                      </svg>
  <!--Text: Title-->
  <svg x="1.5504" y="1.2375" width="2.02212" height="0.4732799999999999">
                          <text x="1.6851" y="0.2805333333333333" text-anchor="end" font-size="0.16666666666666666" font-family="Arial" font-weight="400" font-style="italic" fill="#000000" transform="rotate(0 1.01106 0.23663999999999996)">
                              ghdfghdfgh
                          </text>
                      </svg>
  </svg>
</g>
</g>

<defs>
  <style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
      font-family: &#x27;
      Arial&#x27;
      ;
      src: url(&#x27;file:///G:/Work/NPGC/assets/fonts/Arial.ttf&#x27;) format(&#x27;
      truetype&#x27;
      );
    }
  </style>
</defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the proportions you want to achieve for the flags? I can't make head nor tail of the screenshot and your comments.

Comment: Imagine designing a badge to wear on your lapel and then wanting to see how it would look if the physical badge was displayed at a 90 degree angle. you would still want all the text and images right side up. I'll add a screenshot of the end product

Comment: The flags in both variants have different aspect ratios. How, precisely, should their sizes change?

Comment: so if the width of the image took up 15% of the width of the badge, the new width should be 15% of the height when the badge is rotated 90 degrees, but to print properly on the designated sheet, the whole badge needs to be rotates 90 degrees. I hope that makes sense, it's a brain teaser to say the least. It makes a lot of sense with the physical product in hand

Comment: aspect ratios should have the same behaviour as what it was already set before (the end user will be able to choose what aspect ratio they want -> stretch or maintain)

Answer (score 0):

I am not the least sure I have understood what you mean when you say "keeping all original proportions". My interpretation is that you refer to percentages of the badge width/height.

The best way to write this is to rotate not the individual components, but the  badge as a whole:

1. Define one badge in landscape proportions, and the other in portrait proportions. Set respective width, height and viewBox for both.
2. The content elements get identical attributes for both variants: x and y for all of them, and width and height for the images all get percentage values.
3. The portrait badge is then rotated and translated so that it sits below the landscape badge.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="8.267in" height="11.692in" viewBox="0 0 8.267 11.692">
    <!-- landscape mode -->
    <svg width="3.8548" height="2.1114" viewBox="0 0 3.8548 2.1114">
        <image xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/gFbTCmq.png;"
               x="8%" y="25%" width="15%" height="15%"
               preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"/>
        <image xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/QLTDr7J.jpg;"
               x="8%" y="63%" width="15%" height="12%"
               preserveAspectRatio="none"/>

        <text x="88%" y="30%" text-anchor="end"
              font-size="0.25" font-family="Arial" font-weight="400"
              font-style="normal" fill="#000000">My Name</text>
        <text x="88%" y="70%" text-anchor="end"
              font-size="0.25" font-family="Arial" font-weight="400"
              font-style="normal" fill="#000000">My Title</text>
    </svg>
    <!-- portrait mode -->
    <svg height="3.8548" width="2.1114" viewBox="0 0 2.1114 3.8548"
         transform="translate(0 4.2228) rotate(-90)">
        <image xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/gFbTCmq.png;"
               x="8%" y="25%" width="15%" height="15%"
               preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"/>
        <image xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/QLTDr7J.jpg;"
               x="8%" y="63%" width="15%" height="12%"
               preserveAspectRatio="none"/>

        <text x="88%" y="30%" text-anchor="end"
              font-size="0.25" font-family="Arial" font-weight="400"
              font-style="normal" fill="#000000">My Name</text>
        <text x="88%" y="70%" text-anchor="end"
              font-size="0.25" font-family="Arial" font-weight="400"
              font-style="normal" fill="#000000">My Title</text>
    </svg>
</svg>
```

I've rotated the portrait variant counter-clockwise. If that is a problem, the clockwise transform would read

```
transform="translate(3.8548 2.1114) rotate(90)"
```

For the template part, you only need to differentiate between the badge dimensions. All internal dimensions stay the same for both badges.